# Ошибка отправки почты через smtplib

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, fastapi, smtplib

При запуске проекта через докер на своей машине все работает хорошо и сообщения отправляются, но при запуске того же кода в докер контейнере на хостинге письмо не отправляется и выпадает исключение

```
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

```
Код отправки письма

async def send_mail(recipient, text):
    sender = 'my_email'
    password = f'{config.email_password}'

    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.starttls()

    try:
        server.login(sender, password)
        msg = MIMEText(f'Это автоматически сгенерированное письмо-уведомление\n{text}')
        msg['Subject'] = 'Error notification'
        server.sendmail(sender, recipient, msg.as_string())

        print(f'Письмо успешно отправлено на {recipient}')

    except Exception as ex:
        print(f'Не получилось отправить письмо {recipient}\n{ex}')
```

Comment: На всякий случай, проверьте открывается ли соединение с почтовым сервисом gmail из контейнера на хостинге? Объективно - не факт. Что-то вроде $ nc -v smtp.gmail.com 587 попробуйте, должно выдать в ответ ... 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP ...  - код 220 говорит, что SMTP служба готова к работе

Comment: @Дмитрий проверил, вернул 200. Когда я просто на хостинге запускаю скрипт для отправки письма все работает хорошо, но в контейнерах не работает. Сама функция для отправки запускается через background_tasks.